# Tax Exemption of Mutual fund which doesn't belongs to ELSS category

Tags: india, tax-deduction, mutual-funds

I am from India, I have mutual fund investment holdings. I have two types of mutual fund category ELSS and NON-ELSS.

I know ELSS category mutual funds will be tax exempted under 80C. But I am not sure about NON-ELSS mutual fund. I may hold these fund more than 3 years. Can declare these funds under 80C.

Example Fund :-

Non-ELSS - ([DSP blackrock micro cap Reg Growth](http://www.moneycontrol.com/mutual-funds/nav/dsp-blackrock-micro-cap-fund-regular-plan/MDS076))

ELSS - ICICI prudential long term tax saving fund

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am not sure about NON-ELSS mutual fund. I may hold these fund more than 3 years. Can declare these funds under 80C

No you cannot get any exemption in tax on regular Mutual funds [Non-ELSS]

The purpose of creation of specific ELSS scheme with 3 years lock-in is to give benefit in taxes.